# Regex or adequate substringing of a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have the following question. I have an input in my program in the lines of:

```
08:47:29.3 X0        LAN          Static IP  192.168.219.1    255.255.255.128  0.0.0.0          1 Gbps Full Duplex                                              
08:47:31.7 X0        LAN          Static IP  192.168.219.1    255.255.255.128  0.0.0.0          1 Gbps Full Duplex 
08:47:38.9 X0        LAN          Static IP  192.168.219.1    255.255.255.128  0.0.0.0          1 Gbps Full Duplex                                              
08:47:40.3 X0        LAN          Static IP  192.168.219.1    255.255.255.128  0.0.0.0          1 Gbps Full Duplex                                             
08:47:43.6 X1        WAN          DHCP       172.22.4.192     255.255.255.0    172.22.4.1       1 Gbps Full Duplex    172.22.1.2   0.0.0.0        0.0.0.0
```

Each line is regarded as a separate string. What would be the best possible way of substringing this, or even better to use a regex for this in order to  store some of the values in variables?

e.g:

```
Name= X0, Type= LAN, Mode= Static IP, IP= 192.168.219.1, Subnet=255.255.255.128, Speed: 1 Gbps Full Duplex
```

The input has variable levels of whitespaces between the "columns" so I though it would be a good idea to try and get anything after two or more spaces using a regex, but I have been unable to get the desired output.

Does anyone have any ideas on how it would be possible to do something like that?

Comment: please provide [mcve] showing what you have tried.

Comment: Looks like you can use `substring` and extract required data by indexes. Or at least split string by spaces.

Comment: @dmitrievanthony, my old implementation was using the way you are saying but it seems that the input I am getting might be variable in terms of length causing the parses to fail.

Comment: @ArisKortex did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Yeap, in fact I did split the string but based on regex pattern (\\s\\s\\s*).

This way I was able to get all the necessary data, since the only suitable and common pattern was the fact that there were more than 2 spaces between the information

Answer (score 0):

without a regex it would be like this: `line=line.split("  ");` 
with regex `line.split(" {2,}");`

now you have to split the first string to only get the name

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new type of object:

```
public class Information {
    private String name, type, mode, ip, subnet, speed;

    public Information(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
        this.name = parts[0];
        this.type = parts[1];
        this.mode = (parts[2] + " " + parts[3]);
        this.ip = parts[4];
        this.subnet = parts[5];
        this.speed = parts[7] + " " + parts[8] + " " + parts[9] + " " + parts[10];
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * @return the mode
     */
    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ip
     */
    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    /**
     * @return the subnet
     */
    public String getSubnet() {
        return subnet;
    }

    /**
     * @return the speed
     */
    public String getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

}
```

and then the class you created contains the information.

Comment: Your split regex will split the string into single characters. You need `\\s+` (not `\\s*`)

Comment: @Bohemian, yes I just noticed that XD. my edit fixed that problem.

Comment: Are you sure? OP says *The input has variable levels of whitespaces between the "columns"*

Comment: @Bohemian yes, I think my internet is lagging, which might cause the edits to missmatched...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `regexp` you can try something like this:

```
String str = "08:47:29.3 X0 LAN Static IP 192.168.219.1 255.255.255.128 0.0.0.0 1 Gbps Full Duplex";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(.+?\\s+.+?)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(.+?\\s+.+?)\\s+(.+)$").matcher(str);
if (matcher.matches()) {
        String time = matcher.group(1);
        String name = matcher.group(2);
        String type = matcher.group(3);
        String mode = matcher.group(4);
        String ip = matcher.group(5);
        String subnet = matcher.group(6);
        String speed = matcher.group(7);
}
```